# ¿Cómo registrar usuarios en firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

En la documentacion oficial de firebase muestra el siguiente codigo para [registrar nuevos usuarios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start?authuser=0):

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```

Desafortunadamente el metodo `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` solo recibe dos parametros un email y password, pero en mi caso yo necesito registrar usuarios ingresando su nombre, apellido, fecha nacimiento, genero, ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?, soy nuevo en Firebase.

Comment: Como lo indica [la misma documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#user_properties), no puedes agregar otras propiedades a tu colección de usuarios en Firebase. Lo que te recomiendo es que agregues un documento o colección tu base de datos donde agregues dicha información, utilizando como llave el ID de cada usuario en dicha colección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estas completando todos los campos del usuario en tu form de registro, obtene los datos y usa el callback de success de registro para mandar como dice Fer dentro de ese UID los datos del form que completaste

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Aca vas a mandar los datos del usuario
                Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(nombre);
                mDatabase.child(user.getUid()).setValue(apellido);
                ...
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }

            // ...
        }
    });
```